# Python Peer-to-Peer Chat (Sockets)

Tags: python, sockets

I've been tasked with creating a peer-to-peer chat application, but I'm having trouble actually sending messages.

Essentially, the user should be prompted for both the IP and port of the person they want to connect to, and then send/receive message continuously.

However, it seems as if a "random" connection is being made immediately after running the program.

Error:

```
Please enter the address you would like to connect on: 127.0.0.1
Please enter the port you would like to connect on: 5000
You: Established connection with:  ('127.0.0.1', 2811)
```

Why is there a connection on port 2811? It is almost as if the program is connecting to itself.

Code:

```
import socket
import threading

LOCALHOST = '127.0.0.1'
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def main():

    class ChatListener(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.port = None

        def run(self):
            listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            listen_socket.bind((LOCALHOST, self.port))
            listen_socket.listen(1)

            while True:

                connection, address = listen_socket.accept()

                print("Established connection with: ", address)

                message = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                print("Them: ", message)

    class ChatSender(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.address = None
            self.port = None

        def run(self):
            send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            send_socket.connect((self.address, self.port))

            while True:

                message = input("You: ")

                if message.lower() == "quit":
                    break
                else:
                    try:
                        send_socket.sendall(message)
                    except:
                        Exception

    ip = input("Please enter the address you would like to connect on: ")
    port = int(input("Please enter the port you would like to connect on: "))

    chat_listener = ChatListener()
    chat_listener.port = port
    chat_listener.start()

    chat_sender = ChatSender()
    chat_sender.address = ip
    chat_sender.port = port
    chat_sender.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You could have passed the arguments directly in the constructor

Answer (score 4):

This is a misunderstanding about sockets and ports. The server (ChatListener) is LISTENING on port 5000 for connections. Imagine 127.0.0.1:5000 to be the server's phone number. However, the client (ChatSender) is free to use any port it wants on its end, and will typically pick one that's not allotted for something else. The client will have a different "phone number" that it is calling from. What you're seeing printed is not the server's "phone number" (127.0.0.1:5000) but rather the "caller ID" for the incoming call (127.0.0.1:2811), which is not on the same port.

Here's a clarifying example. Imagine for a moment that the sender is actually on a different machine, at some different IP address, say 127.0.0.2. The client initiates a socket, attempting to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000. It allocates a miscellaneous port, say 2811 to make the connection from. If successful, the server is connected to 127.0.0.2:2811. Any time the client wants to send some data, it's going to send it to 127.0.0.1:5000. However, any time the server wants to send data back to the client, it's going to do so on 127.0.0.2:2811. Let me know if this example is unclear and I will try to clarify further.

Comment: Ah, I believe I understand it now. Thanks!

So essentially, the IP/Port pair is necessary for listening.

So if Chat 1 wanted to talk to Chat 2, it needs Chat 2's IP/Port so it can listen for Chat 2. 

Similarly, if Chat 2 wants to talk back to Chat 1, it will need Chat 1's IP/Port so it can listen for Chat 1. 

---

Now assume I want to run this code for 2 different users so they can talk to each other. Is it possible to just create one socket per user and use it for both listening and sending?

Comment: No problem! Once you get your code fully working, I imagine it'll be like this: Chat 1 wants to talk to Chat 2. Chat 2 must already have a server (listener) thread running on a known port. Chat 1 initiates a connection to the IP/port of that that listener. From there two-way communication can proceed using just that socket. Chat 1 will have one thread listening for received data on the socket, and another thread transmitting data on that socket. Mirror that for Chat 2.

Comment: Excellent. So just to clarify, I can use 1 socket and 1 socket only to both send and receive between two different machines (assume this is the case, but for testing it wont necessarily be)